# How to add space between feedback stars?

Tags: html, css

I have created five feedback stars using HTML and CSS. Below is the image for the same.

[image]

As you can see that stars are way too close to each-other. I want to apply some space between the stars. I have used margin, padding everything. But nothing is working. Below is the code:

```css
.ratings {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #b1b1b1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.full-stars {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fde16d;
}

.empty-stars:before,
.full-stars:before {
  content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605";
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.empty-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #848484;
}

.full-stars:before {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}


/* Firefox */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .full-stars {
    color: #ECBE24;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="empty-stars"></div>
  <div class="full-stars" style="width:70%"></div>
</div>
```

Below is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4qqspqxh/862/

Could you please help me to make some gap in between the stars?

Comment: Please do not use external code sites when asking questions here on StackOverflow. The only viable reason to do that is if your code requires features not supported by SO snippet functionality.

Comment: @connexo did you downvote my question? Earlier when I never used to put fiddle, people bashed me for not putting fiddle link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {
   content: "\2605\2605\2605\2605";
   font-size: 14pt;
   letter-spacing: 4pt;
}
```

Comment: If this solution worked for you kindly accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {
    content:"\2605\2605\2605\2605";
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Give spaces changes in content like this::

```
.empty-stars:before, .full-stars:before {
    content:"\2605  \2605  \2605  \2605";
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```